# Ёщ, как имя.

Tags: общие-вопросы

Слово "ёж" в творительном падеже меняет "ё" на "е", становясь "ежом"
Аналогично "ёрш" становится "ершом".

Возник вопрос. Если мы придумаем имя, скажем, "Ёщ", то как оно будет склоняться по падежам? Сменит ли "е" "ё"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По наблюдениям  Суперанской **(Суперанская А.В. "Словарь личных имён")** --

1. При склонении мужских имён ударение обычно сохраняется на том же гласном звуке, что и в именительном падеже. Имён, оканчивающихся на твёрдый согласный, у которых ударение в косвенных падежах переносится на окончание, всего три: *Пётр, Лев* и, как ни странно (по крайней мере для меня), *Фрол.*
2. **Если имя оканчивается на шипящий** или на *"ц"*, в творительном падеже пишется не *"-ом",* а *"-ем"* : *Юмаш-ем, Жорж-ем, Ференц-ем, Казбич-ем.* Правда, ни одного имени, оканчивающегося на *"щ",* Суперанская не приводит.

===

В сказках *Ёж* (как имя собственное у ежа), склоняется с переносом ударения на окончание (и с заменой *Ё* на *Е*): *Ежом.* Но, думаю, если б имя ***Ёж*** было дано при рождении какому-либо ребёнку, вряд ли бы его стали склонять, как у сказочного персонажа. Скорее, склонялось бы это имя так же, как и *Жорж:*
***Ёж, Ёжа, Ёжу, Ёжем…***

Так же, думаю, склонялся бы и ***Ёщ.***

Comment: В пьесе М.Горького "На дне" один из персонажей - Клещ

Answer (score 2):

Поскольку в русском языке ударение подвижное и свободное, то ответить точно на этот вопрос невозможно. Во всех приведенных случаях окончание творительного падежа "ем-ём" считается традиционным.  А принимая во внимание, что приведенное вами имя выдуманное, то ответить на вопрос, какое окончание оно будет иметь в творительном падеже - ответить сложно. Решение должен принимать автор. Можно и сохранить окончание - "ем" по аналогии с уже сложившимися словами: "ёж - ежoм", ёрш - ершом".